How to remove margin in ggvenn plotted with ggplot?
I am trying to create a venn diagram with the ggvenn package utilizing ggplot2. However, when I save the image with ggsave there is a lot of white space around the image. I tried to set the margins using par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)) as well as in the plot code itself.
Reproducible example
library(ggvenn)
library(ggplot2)
d <- tibble(value   = c(1,     2,     3,     5,     6,     7,     8,     9),
            `Set 1` = c(TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE),
            `Set 2` = c(TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
            `Set 3` = c(TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE),
            `Set 4` = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE))

p2 = ggplot(d, aes(A = `Set 1`, B = `Set 2`)) +
  geom_venn(fill_color = c("white", "white"), show_percentage = FALSE) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",colour = "white"),
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks=element_blank(),
      axis.title.x=element_blank(),
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      legend.position="none",
      panel.border=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
      plot.background=element_blank()) +
      theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))

#ggsave(plot = p2, "/plot2.tiff"


the result is an image with large white margins
https://imgur.com/a/N28KbZi
How can I reduce the margins?
I tried reducing the margins using par(mar=c(0,0,0,0) and theme (plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0),"mm"))

Two suggestions (that are both maybe suboptimal); (1) your margins can also be negative, i.e., theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(rep(-20, 4), "mm")). (2) You can use the magick package to trim of the whitespace of images: image_read("plot2.tiff") |> image_trim() |> image_write("plot2_trimmed.tiff")

To get actual circles in your Venn diagram, you probably want to use coord_fixed(). Turn off axis expansion using expand = FALSE. We can add theme_void() which removes all axes and margins etc.
ggplot(d, aes(A = `Set 1`, B = `Set 2`)) +
  geom_venn(fill_color = c("white", "white"), show_percentage = FALSE) +
  coord_fixed(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_void()

This should give a plot with reasonable margins.

If you want to reduce them further, give more stringent axis limits to coord_fixed(), e.g.:
coord_fixed(expand = FALSE, xlim = c(-1.7, 1.7), ylim = c(-1.4, 1.4))



I ended up changing the values in the theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm")) to
theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(-7,-3,-10,-3), "cm")) which got exactly what I wanted. But thank you for the alternate solution.
